# hbase checkAndPut for existing value or greater or equal

Tags: hbase

I need to have a checkandput operation for the following condition:

1: exists 
2: with value less than specified value.

The put operation will be executed if the value is not existed or the value is less than a specific value.

I know it has two versions for checkandput and I can implement either condition with one of requests. But I don't know how I can check both conditions with one atomic call.

```
boolean checkAndPut(byte[] row, byte[] family, byte[] qualifier, byte[] value, Put put)
boolean checkAndPut(byte[] row, byte[] family, byte[] qualifier, CompareFilter.CompareOp compareOp, byte[] value,Put put)
```

Thanks in advance!

James

Answer (score 0):

**Unlike RDBMS,There is nothing like null in HBase or most of KeyValue stores.**

> HBase has dynamic schema. So, every row can have different columns unlike RDBMS DB's.

So, you dont need to write the column to row if its value is null. I think, you should use:

```
boolean checkAndPut(byte[] row, byte[] family, byte[] qualifier, CompareFilter.CompareOp compareOp, byte[] value,Put put)
```

If you just want to check whether it null or not? Then just check for existence of that column in that row.

Comment: Yes. I want to check the existence. if it exists, we will check the value, then put.  If it is not there, we will run the put directly. How to do that. thanks

Comment: Yes. I tried. it works with existing value, but not with non-existing value.

Comment: Then you need to use both the methods. 
 OR
You can enhance(submit a patch in HBase) the method so that it also start working with non-existing value.